# GNOME desktop doesn't load, no Dock icons appear

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

A few days ago, after booting up and logging in to my account I got this blank screen on which only the purple background and the Panel were visible.

Screenshot showing GNOME desktop with an empty Dock and the top bar is visible:

[image: screenshot showing Gnome with only the top bar visible]

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Can you click on anything? What happens if you click on the Activities on the top left? What did it used to look like compared to what you see now? Please [edit] and give us some context.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click anywhere in the desktop wallpaper and select *Open in Terminal* to launch the terminal. Otherwise you may need to access a virtual console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and logging in. To login from a virtual console do as follows.

   - At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   sudo dconf reset -f /org/gnome/shell
   setsid gnome-shell
   ```
3. If you are in a virtual console access the desktop environment by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.